# Excel export didn't support Arabic language using php

Tags: php, excel, xls

I have tried to excel export with the format of xls. but it didn't support Arabic language.The sample code is below, example text is : Fars Province, Shiraz, آزادگان، پلاک 2, Iran

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream, charset=UTF-16; encoding=UTF-16");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.xls");
echo $xls_output;
exit;
```

this is result that i got : Fars Province, Shiraz, Ø¢Ø²Ø§Ø¯Ú¯Ø§Ù†ØŒ Ù¾Ù„Ø§Ú© 2, Iran

Thanks for advance reply,

Comment: So hw are you generating `$xls_output;`? Is this real Excel format data, or are you generating html or csv and pretending that it's excel?

Comment: hi sir, am using table format, data's are saved to $xls_output.

Comment: You mean you're content is just html markup?

Comment: MS Excel's html import is far from perfect, but have you ensured that your markup specifies UTF-8 in the heading? `<meta charset="UTF-8">` (assuming that you are using UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Use the html5 as template also use below code header ,ARABC and other languages appear every well

```
 @header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
 @header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.xls\"");
```